# a new list and erase from the initial list. The procedure should keep on going until there is no element in the

Tags: python, arraylist

enhance the program such that your code should get the last element from the list and then get the first and the second and so on until the sum is higher than or  equal to 600 and add those elements to a new list and erase from the initial list. The procedure should keep on going until there is no element in the initial list.

array example:[78, 96, 120, 133, 145, 152, 277, 278, 285, 298, 299, 304, 305]

then the result should be like
[305, 78, 120], [304, 96, 145], [299, 133, 159]

this is my code:

```
import os
import csv
with open("dr_S03_2_2018_800.txt", "r") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
print('line[{}] = {}'.format(i, line))
```

Comment: You just print index and line. You don't tried anything in your code... Try something.

Comment: I've tried but I didnt do that

Comment: First step : create your initial list with your file data.
Tips - You can get last element of a list in python like this : list[-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably do something like the following:

```
inputs = [78, 96, 120, 133, 145, 152, 277, 278, 285, 298, 299, 304, 305]

curr_list = []
outputs = []

for i in range(-1, len(inputs) - 1):
    curr_list.append(inputs[i])
    if sum(curr_list) >= 600:
        outputs.append(curr_list)
        curr_list = []

inputs = []

print(outputs)
```